Py-Spark code is taking too long to execute for multiple transformation on same data frame
I am writing a generic script to perform data validations in pyspark. This involves a data set to be run through every rule and for failed columns I am creating a column and adding a rule_id to indicate what row has failed which rules.
Problem here is, the spark code is taking way to too long to execute and is not completing when ran in my AWS glue job and is giving java memory exception in my local.
As I am new to py-spark need your suggestions what can be done to make this optimized. If less than 3 rules it is working fine more than that it is not completing.
Code as follows :
 source_df = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
.option("inferSchema", "true") \
.option("delimiter", '|').csv(args["process_s3_path"])

 all_columns = source_df.columns

 for data_quality_rule in data_quality_dataset_rules:
     rule_id = data_quality_rule["rule_id"]
     rule_type = data_quality_rule["rule_type"]
     cols_applicable = all_columns if data_quality_rule["cols_applicable"] == "*" else 
     data_quality_rule["cols_applicable"].split(',')
     value = data_quality_rule["value_pattern"]

if rule_type == "GROUP_DISTINCT":
    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(cols_applicable)
    source_df = source_df.withColumn("count", count("*").over(windowSpec))
    source_df = source_df.withColumn(rule_id, 
                    when(col("count") > 1, lit(rule_id))
                    .otherwise(lit(''))
                )
    source_df = source_df.drop('count')

if rule_type == "GROUP_DISTINCT_FOR_VALUE":
    filter_condition = col(f'failed.{cols_applicable[0]}').isNotNull()
    for column in cols_applicable[1:]:
        filter_condition = filter_condition & col(f'failed.{column}').isNotNull()
    
    failed_groups = source_df.groupBy(cols_applicable) \
        .agg(countDistinct(value).alias("distinct_d_count")) \
        .filter(col("distinct_d_count") > 1)
    
    source_df = source_df.alias("source") \
        .join(failed_groups.alias("failed"), cols_applicable, 'left') \
        .withColumn(rule_id, when(filter_condition, lit(rule_id)).otherwise(lit(''))) \
        .drop('distinct_d_count')

 when_exprs = [when(col(column) != '', col(column)).otherwise(None) for column in 
        rule_ids]

 source_df = source_df.withColumn("dq_failed_rules", concat_ws(",", *when_exprs))
 source_df = source_df.drop(*[col_name for col_name in rule_ids])

 valid_dq = source_df.filter(col('dq_failed_rules') == '')
 invalid_dq = source_df.filter(col('dq_failed_rules') != '')

 print(f"invalid_dq count :: {invalid_dq.count()}")


After every Nth transformation (N = 3 or 4 or 5 etc, play with value) materialize the dataframe with. df.cache.foreach(lambda x: x). Having long lineage of transformations slows down final evaluation so it takes more time.
